# Discord.js can't read properties

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a ban command using discord.js, but I can't make it work. It always reply with "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')"

The code:

```
async run(message, args, client) {
    if (message.author.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS)) {
        if (message.members.mentions.first()) {
            try {
                message.members.mentions.first().kick();
            } catch {
                message.reply("I don't have permission to ban" + message.members.mentions.first());
            }
        } else {
            message.reply("You cannot ban " + message.members.mentions.first());
        }
    }

}
```

I tried looking up some sample codes but it still doesn't work for me

Comment: Assuming `message` is a discord.js Message, `message.author` would be a User or undefined. You are probably looking for [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member). On top of that, `members` is not a property of Message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Message.author` is a `User` instance, which `.permissions` doesn't exist on. Use `Message.member` instead to get the `GuildMember`.

Also, as stated by [@user15517071](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15517071/user15517071) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70429623/discord-js-cant-read-properties#comment124498775_70429623), you need to use `Message.mentions.members` instead of `Message.members.mentions`

Here is the edited code

```js
async run(message, args, client) {
    if (message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS)) {
        if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
            try {
                message.mentions.members.first().kick();
            } catch {
                message.reply("I don't have permission to ban" + message.mentions.members.first());
            }
        } else {
            message.reply("You cannot ban " + message.members.mentions.first());
        }
    }

}
```