# Discord.js kick command permissions problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So the last question I asked, I tried to use the sample code in MrMythical answer. This time, I encountered another problem:

```
if (message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS)){
                                   ^
    ReferenceError: Permissions is not defined
```

The code:

```js
module.exports = new Command({
    name: "kick",
    description: "kick",

    async run(message, args, client) {
    if (message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS)) {
        if (message.mentions.members) {
            try {
                message.mentions.kick();
            } catch {
                message.reply("I don't have permission to ban " + message.mentions.members.first());
            }
        } else {
            message.reply("You cannot ban " + message.member.mentions.first());
        }
    }

    }
});
```

Let's say I deleted the `if (message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS))`, the message the returned when executing the command was `I don't have permission to ban <insert_user_id>`.

I'm kinda stuck here for a while, if you can help me, thank you so much.

Edit: I forgot to import the Permissions, so there's just "Don't have permissions to kick" now

Comment: You probably need to import `Permissions`

Comment: There was already a `Permissions` variable in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70429623/6126373). I don't really understand how it's no longer defined. Have you imported it from `discord.js`?

Comment: I totally forgot to import the Permissions, still I cant manage to kick a user

Comment: @SakuraKaslana I've just updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to import `Permissions` from `discord.js`. You can import it at the top of the page, like this:

```js
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');
```

Also, [`message.mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions) returns an object and it includes the mentioned members, channels, and roles. It won't have a `kick()` method and if you try to call it, it will throw an error. As you don't log the error in your `catch` block, you will have no idea what the error is; it will just send a reply saying "You cannot ban undefined".

You will need to check if there are mentioned members by checking [`message.mentions.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members). It returns a collection; you can grab the first member by using [`first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=first).

You can kick the first mentioned member like this:

```js
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = new Command({
  name: 'kick',
  description: 'kick',
  async run(message, args, client) {
    if (!message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS))
      return message.reply('You have no permission to ban members');

    if (!message.mentions.members)
      return message.reply('You need to mention a member to ban');

    let mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();

    try {
      mentionedMember.kick();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      message.reply(`Oops, there was an error banning ${mentionedMember}`);
    }
  },
});
```